# How to echo out payment amount to customer after successful purchase with paypal sdk?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I can successfully create payment with paypal rest sdk.

And the code below belongs to page I redirect successful customers.

**success.php**

```
// #Execute Payment Sample
// This is the second step required to complete
// PayPal checkout. Once user completes the payment, paypal
// redirects the browser to "redirectUrl" provided in the request.

require "app/start.php";

use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
// ### Approval Status
// Determine if the user approved the payment or not
if (isset($_GET['paymentId']) && $_GET['token'] && $_GET['PayerID']) {
    // Get the payment Object by passing paymentId
    // payment id was previously stored in session in
    // CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php
    $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
    // ### Payment Execute
    // PaymentExecution object includes information necessary
    // to execute a PayPal account payment.
    // The payer_id is added to the request query parameters
    // when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($_GET['PayerID']);

    try {
        // Execute the payment
        // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $paypal);
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        //ResultPrinter::printResult("Executed Payment", "Payment", $payment->getId(), $execution, $result);
        echo $payment->getId();
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump($result);

        try {
            $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
            //ResultPrinter::printError("Get Payment", "Payment", null, null, $ex);
            echo "error 1";
            exit(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        //ResultPrinter::printError("Executed Payment", "Payment", null, null, $ex);
        echo "error 2";
        exit(1);
    }
    // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
    //ResultPrinter::printResult("Get Payment", "Payment", $payment->getId(), null, $payment);

    //return $payment;
} else {
    // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
    //ResultPrinter::printResult("User Cancelled the Approval", null);
    echo "cancelled";
    exit;
}
```

And here is what I echo out for successful ones:

```
echo $payment->getId();
echo "<br>";
var_dump($result);
```

Anyway, I would like to echo out something like *You have successfully paid $X.00.*

But I don't know how to grab total payment amount from what I have got.

```
var_dump($result);
```

prints this:

```
>object(stdClass)#36 (10) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(28) "PAY-XXXXXXXXXX"
  ["intent"]=>
  string(4) "sale"
  ["state"]=>
  string(8) "approved"
  ["cart"]=>
  string(17) "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["payer"]=>
  object(stdClass)#35 (2) {
    //payer details was here
  }
  ["transactions"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#29 (4) {
      ["amount"]=>
      object(stdClass)#27 (3) {
        ["total"]=>
        string(5) "25.00"
        ["currency"]=>
        string(3) "USD"
        ["details"]=>
        object(stdClass)#23 (3) {
          ["subtotal"]=>
          string(5) "25.00"
          ["tax"]=>
          string(4) "0.00"
          ["shipping"]=>
          string(4) "0.00"
        }
      }

  //and goes on....
```

So, I'm really very close to get the total amount. I need a little bit help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best practise but,

```
$result->transactions[0]->related_resources[0]->sale->amount->total; //echo: 25.00
```

this code solved my problem so far.